# Assigning onClick with a parameter to a component inside of map function React

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-thompson-cu720?file=/src/App.js

I'm rendering an array of strings using map and attempting to set the state of a variable to the name of the string that is clicked. Unfortunately, my onClick doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```js
function Message(props) {
  return <button>{props.name}</button>;
}

...
const names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Tom"];
const [selected, setSelected] = useState("none selected");

return (
  <div className="App">
    {selected}
    <div>
      {names.map(name => (
        <Message name={name} onClick={() => setSelected(name)} />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Message` component doesn't have a click event listener by default. You have to add bind the click event on your `button` inside the `Message` component:

```js
function Message(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.name}</button>;
}
```